# Get hostname of your workspace

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there a way to get the public hostname of the workspace node for a Cloud9 workspace from the environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the **export** command in the console, you can see the defined environment variables.

The variable you are looking for is **"C9_HOSTNAME"**.